# bash script - while IFS causes program to hang

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've got a file (file1.txt) that looks like like

```
0,100,500
0,200,300
etc.
```

For each line, I need to run a program that will use some of this data as arguments.

Hence I wrote:

```
while IFS=',' read -r parameter1 parameter2 parameter3; do
/path/to/program/./program.bin -arg2 "$parameter2" -arg3 "$parameter3" 
done < file1.txt
```

When running the script, the program starts but it hangs and becomes totally unresponsive.

The funny thing is that when doing:

```
while IFS=',' read -r parameter1 parameter2 parameter3; do
echo /path/to/program/./program.bin -arg2 "$parameter2" -arg3 "$parameter3" >> commands.txt
done < file1.txt
```

and then

```
bash -i commands.txt
```

It works. The programs starts normally, finishes then runs again.

I don't have any background in IT and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Excuse me if the vocabulary I'm using isn't adequate.

Comment: Is `program.bin` reading from standard input? (I don't think the problem is `IFS`, but redirecting stdin)

Comment: It does start with the right arguments but then it hangs, it's as if the script was not letting it finish / trying to run it multiple times at once or something like that?

Comment: But does it read from stdin? If so, both the loop and your program are reading from `file1.txt` (which is redirected to stdin). You can try closing stdin for your program: `program.bin </dev/null`, `program.bin <&-`, or `:|program.bin`

Comment: The program doesn't read from standard input

Comment: Can you still try to close stdin or redirecting something which cannot be read?

Comment: Ok, so I've found something. You can interact with the program in the console by sending inputs (ex: 'S' for start, 'P' for pause) and it looks as if the script is sending commands that the program cannot interpret. I think that's what you meant by your question?

Comment: I've tried adding your suggestions but it doesn't work :/

Comment: Yes, that means the program is reading from standard input. Standard input is redirected from `file.txt`. You have to force the program to read from somewhere else or don't read anything at all. If you do the `bash -i commands.txt` thing, are you expected to enter S or P?

Comment: I'm not expected to enter anything, but I can. The program always listens for stdin. I see what the problem is, but this is beyond what I'm able to do. I'm going to rewrite the script entirely. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: All three solutions of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74223388/112968) should work then. Can you confirm?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249111/discussion-between-bobylapointe-and-knittl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go see [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74223697/112968), it solves the problem in a more straightforward way.

Your program is very likely reading from standard input. Your `file.txt` is redirected to standard input, so both `read` and your program will try to read from the file. You have to force your program to read a different input or not read at all.

```
while IFS=',' read -r parameter1 parameter2 parameter3; do
  # /dev/null cannot be read from:
  /path/to/program/./program.bin -arg2 "$parameter2" -arg3 "$parameter3" </dev/null
done < file1.txt
```

```
while IFS=',' read -r parameter1 parameter2 parameter3; do
  # read user input from console:
  /path/to/program/./program.bin -arg2 "$parameter2" -arg3 "$parameter3" </dev/tty
done < file1.txt
```

```
while IFS=',' read -r parameter1 parameter2 parameter3; do
  # ":" builtin doesn't produce any output
  : | /path/to/program/./program.bin -arg2 "$parameter2" -arg3 "$parameter3"
done < file1.txt
```

Comment: It's working with '</dev/tty'  !!! You're the man !!

Answer (score 3):

In general, if the body of your loop can read from some file descriptor (in this case, standard input), it's better to use a *different* file descriptor for your `read` command.

```
# Assuming program.bin does not read from file descriptor 3.
while IFS=',' read -r parameter1 parameter2 parameter3 <&3; do
    /path/to/program/./program.bin -arg2 "$parameter2" -arg3 "$parameter3" 
done 3< file1.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will use your tip in the future.